# HTTP Status code 500 from trivial $.getJSON call - why?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, httpresponse

I have stripped my `getJSON` call to the simplest example possible trying to figure out why it's not working but I'm out of ideas. I currently have:

```
public JsonResult MyAction()
{
    return Json(new { status = "OK" });
}

$.getJSON('MyController/MyAction', function(result) { alert('worked'); });
```

The action is called, but the alert does not get fired and looking in Chrome developer tools I see a Status 500 error code is returned. What can possibly be causing this? How can I debug it?

Comment: Have you looked into the server's error logs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default MVC 2.0 blocks GET requests to actions that return a `JsonResult`.

Use `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` to force the issue, or use POST.

```
public JsonResult MyAction()
{
    return Json(new { status = "OK" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Or use post:

```
$.post('MyController/MyAction', function(result) {
    alert('worked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls, use firebug (or fiddler) in the Network tab, choose XHR, to see what you send and receive.

As Michael Shimmins says, MVC 2 blocks Get requests by default, because of Json Hijacking.
Here is an interesting article:

http://www.ifunky.net/blog/post/AspNet-MVC-2-JsonRequestBehaviorAllowGet.aspx

They talk here about this message:
"This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request."

Answer (score 0):

I think that MyController/MyAction is relative to whatever url you are now. try 'MyController/MyAction'.

EDIT: Also try to call MyController/MyAction from whichever url you are currently and check that it returns the desired result

EDIT: Actually thats not the problem. As Michael pointed out this would return a 404 error.